# How to display Multiple phone numbers of same contact in RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I'm using a library called `MultiContactsPicker` ([redirect link to the library](https://github.com/broakenmedia/MultiContactPicker)).

It displays only first phone number of contacts. I want to display all phone numbers of the contact.

It fetches all phone numbers of the contact but displays only first one. Please see code below:

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, @SuppressLint("RecyclerView") final int i) {
        if(holder instanceof ContactViewHolder) {
            ContactViewHolder contactViewHolder = (ContactViewHolder) holder;
            final Contact contactItem = getItem(i);
            contactViewHolder.tvContactName.setText(contactItem.getDisplayName());
            contactViewHolder.vRoundLetterView.setTitleText(String.valueOf(contactItem.getDisplayName().charAt(0)));
            contactViewHolder.vRoundLetterView.setBackgroundColor(contactItem.getBackgroundColor());
            if (contactItem.getPhoneNumbers().size() > 0) {
                String phoneNumber = contactItem.getPhoneNumbers().**get(0)**.getNumber().replaceAll("\\s+", "");
                String displayName = contactItem.getDisplayName().replaceAll("\\s+", "");
                if (!phoneNumber.equals(displayName)) {
                    contactViewHolder.tvNumber.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    contactViewHolder.tvNumber.setText(phoneNumber);
                }
                else {
                    contactViewHolder.tvNumber.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
             }
```

Comment: inside your if block you can have a for loop that goes through all the contactItem.getPhoneNumbers() and concatenates them in a new string with \n character at the end

Comment: I tried but app is crashing.

Comment: what was the error? android:singleLine="false" maybe this should solve on the contactViewHolder.tvNumber in the XML